# Getting 404 Not Found nginx 1.6.2 on Paytm

Tags: python, react-native, react-native-ios, paytm

I have followed the usage as per link below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paytm

This is my checksum generation code:

```
import Checksum
# initialize a dictionary
paytmParams = dict()

# put checksum parameters in Dictionary
paytmParams["MID"] = "*****************"
paytmParams["ORDER_ID"] = 'ORD001'
paytmParams["CUST_ID"] = 'CUST001'
paytmParams["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = 'Retail' 
paytmParams["CHANNEL_ID"] = 'WAP'
paytmParams["TXN_AMOUNT"] = '1.00'
paytmParams["WEBSITE"] = 'WEBSTAGING'
paytmParams["EMAIL"] = '**************'
paytmParams["MOBILE_NO"] = '****************'
paytmParams["CALLBACK_URL"] = 'https://securegw- 
stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORD001'    

# Find your Merchant Key in your Paytm Dashboard at 
https://dashboard.paytm.com/next/apikeys
checksum = Checksum.generate_checksum(paytmParams, "*************")
```

Code for react native:

```
import paytm from 'react-native-paytm';
import { Platform, DeviceEventEmitter, NativeModules,NativeEventEmitter} from 'react-native';

const paytmConfig = {
  MID: '************',
  WEBSITE: 'WEBSTAGING',
  CHANNEL_ID: 'WAP',
  INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: 'Retail',
  CALLBACK_URL: 'https://securegw- 
  stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORD001'
}
onPayTmResponse(response) {
    // Process Response
    // response.response in case of iOS
    // reponse in case of Android
    console.log(response);
}

 runTransaction() {
     const callbackUrl = 'https://securegw- 
   stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORD001'
    const details = {
      mode: 'Staging', // 'Staging' or 'Production'
      mid: paytmConfig.MID,
      industryType: paytmConfig.INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID,
      website: paytmConfig.WEBSITE,
      channel: paytmConfig.CHANNEL_ID,
      amount: '1.00', // String
      orderId: 'ORD001', // String
      custId: 'CUST001', // String
      email: '*****************', // String
      phone: '***********', // S
      checksumhash: '***********************************************', //From your server using PayTM Checksum Utility 
      callback: callbackUrl
    };
    paytm.startPayment(details);
}
```

The issue is that i cant even spot the error point here as there is no console. I could use some direction here. Need this for staging right now

Answer (score 0):

in my cash use this npm @philly25/react-native-paytm and solved this error 
    are you sure onPaytmResponse is a paytm listener
    like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    Paytm.addListener(Paytm.Events.PAYTM_RESPONSE, this.onPayTmResponse)
};

componentWillUnmount() {
    Paytm.removeListener(Paytm.Events.PAYTM_RESPONSE, this.onPayTmResponse);
};
```